# Apache to Nginx Conversion (Newbie)

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, .htaccess, rewrite

I've got a Nginx Web Server Setup with PHP and I want to move on Nginx and I want to convert these .htaccess rules to nginx.conf file:

```
RewriteRule ^blog(|/)$ /data/core/site/blog.php
RewriteRule ^blog/post(|/)$ /data/core/site/blogpost.php
```

So far this is what I have:

```
location /blog {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /data/core/blog.php last;
    }
```

However if I visit the page (http://example.com/blog), It gives me the file to download, I want it to server the PHP and display content, how would I fix this?

Full Nginx configuration: (Using Winginx Package on Windows):

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name localhost;

    root home/localhost/public_html;

    index index.php;

    log_not_found off;
    #access_log logs/localhost-access.log;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~ /\. { deny all; }
    location = /favicon.ico { }
    location = /robots.txt { }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9054;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /blog {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /data/core/blog.php last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I've updated the question with the full Nginx Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fix to my question, after doing alot of research on issues, I've found out that it was pretty straight forward:

```
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:80;
server_name virjox www.virjox;

root home/virjox/public_html;

index index.php;

log_not_found off;
#access_log logs/virjox-access.log;

charset utf-8;

sendfile on;

location ~ /\. { deny all; }
location = /favicon.ico { }
location = /robots.txt { }  
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9054;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.html /$1\.php;
}
   location /blog {
     rewrite ^/blog(|/)$ /data/core/blog.php;
   }
}
```

and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

## Requests processing

The base rule to remember is: **nginx serves a request with one location** (you could emphase even more: ***and one location only***).

Read: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

## `location` matching

Read: [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation

Based on your configuration, nginx will first match on the `/blog` *prefix* location, then on the `\.php$` *regex* location and will eventually serves the request with the latter. With the configuration you provided, the script should not be downloaded as a raw file any more but should rather by sent over to PHP.

However, that does not mean your configuration is right: the request is not served by your `/blog` location, which is useless at the moment.

1. It is a general good practice to avoid filtering requests with regex locations, which are order-based, which is bad (remember Apache directives order sensitivity nightmare?). To filter, use prefix locations instead which are longest-match-based. You can embed locations withing each other if you ultimately need a regex one.
2. Why not directly putting your `fastcgi*` directives into the `/blog` location? Then, instead of using the `$fastcgi_script_name` variable (guessed from the `location` match that would be variants of `/blog` here), you could use `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/data/core/blog.php`. By the way, `$fastcgi_script_filename` already contained the starting `/`, no need to add one between the variables
3. Avoid using redirections if you can avoid them. Avoid especially `rewrite` even more. Simple user redirections (URL rewriting done through redirection notifications sent to the client with HTTP status codes) can be done with `return`. What you did here was an internal redirection (done locally on the server): its only use was to change the URI then used for the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter.

You could use for starters:

```
location /blog {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9054;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/data/core/blog.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    # Useless here since SCRIPT_FILENAME will never be a directory indeed
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    location /blog/post {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9054;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/data/core/blogpost.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying this out it seems to have the same issue, it still gives me a file to download.

Comment: Ensure your configuration file is OK with `nginx -t` and check that the reload went OK by monitoring the error log. If it is still not working, please provide information on your configuration and the requests you try

Comment: Hello, I've managed to fix the issue, thanks for your help tho! :) I will post the answer shortly.

Comment: Glad it worked. A little bit disappointed you did not follow any piece of advice I took quite some time to explain + added something also not recommended to make the whole even less ideal.